# Class constructor dataLayer cannot be invoked without 'new' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to automate testing of GTM using Puppeteer and [puppeteer-datalayer](https://github.com/justusbluemer/puppeteer-datalayer) node.js module. When I try to instantiate the dataLayer class I however get the following error:  *Class constructor dataLayer cannot be invoked without 'new'*.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
// @ts-ignore
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const puppeteerDl = require('puppeteer-datalayer')

(async () => {

    // Automate here
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const containerId = "GTM-XXXXXX";

    await page.goto('example.com');
    const div = await page.evaluate(() => {return (document.querySelector('p').innerHTML)});

    console.log(div);

    await page.click('div.user-box-links > a');

    const dataLayerPupeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
    const latestEvent = dataLayerPupeteer.getLatestEvent();

    console.log(latestEvent);

    await browser.close();




})();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you import dataLayer as `puppeteerDl ` so i guess you need to do `new puppeteerDl(page, containerId);`

Comment: @domlas i have edited the code. please see the edit

Comment: you still have it wrong. change line `const dataLayerPupeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);`
to `const dataLayerPupeteer = new puppeteerDl(page, containerId);`